# Lucene indexing: shared or isolated by account?

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I'm evaluating Lucene to implement a global search feature in a SaaS application.

We do not want users to see the content of the other accounts so searches will always be limited by account.

Is it better to have one single index with an account id field or one index per account? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

My concern is that a global index might affect performance due to the frequent updates.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

- Estimated number of total documents: 500,0000
- Number of accounts: 4000
- Indexable data is never shared between accounts
- Account users might update their indexable data several times a day (not more than 100 in most cases)
- The amount of indexed data tends to be stable after the initial setup process
- We need to store 10-20 fields per document

Comment: Your question is too broad/complex; the answer depends very much on other aspects of your application and its architecture. What is the running environment in which indexes will be queried? Is indexable data often shared between many accounts? Is data updated often? How often? What is the growth rate of indexed data for a typical account? And so on and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are some things I would think about in addition to the usual problems (e.g. index updates and such):

1. The way lucene returns ranked results depends upon some "corpus-wide" statistics, for example the total number of documents that a term appears in for that field. So, if the index statistics for customer a are inappropriate for customer b, its going to hurt relevance for both customers, besides being a security risk... if oscar is smart enough he truly can start reversing bob's documents because of the nature of the inverted index: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.159.9682 You could probably work around this with something like this ranking algorithm: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2864
2. Some other things in lucene apply to a "field as a whole" or "index as a whole" and you should know that they can't be really changed on a per-customer basis if you group indexes together: things like omitTF (if you set it on a single document for a field, its omitted across the board for that field), similarity (in any released version of lucene, you can only set similarity across the board, so customers wouldn't be able to tune the ranking model), spellchecking (you would have to hack something up, where each customer has their own "filtered" spellcheck index), ...
3. On the other hand, if you have many terms, quite a bit of RAM is required and by giving each customer their own index, you will need more memory to hold the terms index in RAM, for all the indexes. You can however, lower this somewhat by adjusting things like termIndexInterval/Divisor.

Comment: Regarding the paper mentioned in 1., is it correct to say that one can implement their 2nd approach (Query Integration) using a custom search filter?

Comment: Not unless you do something about the IDF... the simplest solution to this for lucene being to use filters + a similarity that does not use any global statistics at all.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, if there is no regulatory reason why you can not, I'd dump them all in to a single index. This is simply my "don't optimize what you don't have to" hat speaking.

The first concern is simply legal: are you even ALLOWED to co-host and intermix data, even if it is separated by logical means. That's up to your lawyers, customers, and service agreements. This is not a technical concern.

Assuming you can, then the next question is what impact will other users have upon each other. If User A is using the system and User B is in the process of importing their 100K documents, is that going to impact User A? Is it impacting User A because of how Lucene works, or simply because of the overall system load that occurs when importing and indexing documents.

Try it and see.

The key thing is to make sure that your client systems do not access Lucene directly, but rather through a facade of some kind. This facade is a perfect place to enforce the client segregation, and it's also a good place to redirect traffic if, at some later time, you decide you need to shard your indexes.

Perhaps you need to tear out a single heavy user. Or you sell a higher level of response time to someone that is guaranteed more resources in their SLA, etc.

But deciding, right now, what the better path is? Eh, seems early.

500K documents is not a lot of data to Lucene. Just make sure you have flexibility in your implementation to add capability later if you find out that hosting it all in a single instance isn't viable. And by "add capability" I mean exactly that, add it. Don't actually IMPLEMENT, say, sharding based on client. But rather have a good point where it COULD be implemented without redoing a bunch of plumbing later.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a few "security trimmed" indexes here and there -- definitely possible if it is allowed. That said, my general inclination with SAAS-type stuff with multiple clients would be to separate the clients as much as possible for a few reasons:

a) Ensures coding errors don't result in data leaks, angry clients, lawsuits and other hoo ha.
b) Makes per-client customization much easier -- your entire codebase need not deal with client-specific fubar requests
c) Forces you into a horizontally scalable architecture from day one -- scaling is easy if adding instances is easy, right?

Oh, and definitely take Will Hartung's advice -- facade search, that stuff really should not creep out of it's layer.